# Plotting a surface contour for a given value in a 3D numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have three 3D mesh matrices (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) corresponding to the xyz coordinate space.

I also have a 3D Numpy matrix `A` where `A[i,j,k]` contains a float that is associated with the point `(x,y,z)` where `x=X[i,j,k]`, `y=Y[i,j,k]`, and `z=Z[i,j,k]`. The float values are continuous within `A` (i.e. the change in value between adjacent elements of `A` are typically small).

Is there a way to plot the surface that corresponds to a given float value in `A` using Matplotlib or any other Python-based graphics package? For example, if given a value `2.34`, I am interested in getting a plotted contour surface of the matrix `A` wherever `2.34` (plus or minus some tolerance) shows up?

So far, I have been able to recover the xyz coordinates of all values in `A` that are within some tolerance of the target value and then make a 3D scatter plot using [this](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) (code below). Perhaps there is also a way of plotting a surface from these points?

```
def clean (A, t, dt):
    # function for making A binary for t+-dt
    # t is the target value I want in the matrix A with tolerance dt
    new_A = np.copy(A)
    new_A[np.logical_and(new_A > t-dt, new_A < t+dt)] = -1
    new_A[new_A != -1] = 0
    new_A[new_A == -1] = 1
    return (new_A)

def get_surface (X, Y, Z, new_A):
    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    z_vals = []

    # Retrieve (x,y,z) coordinates of surface
    for i in range(new_A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(new_A.shape[1]):
            for k in range(new_A.shape[2]):
                if new_A[i,j,k] == 1.0:
                    x_vals.append(X[i,j,k])
                    y_vals.append(Y[i,j,k])
                    z_vals.append(Z[i,j,k])

    return (np.array(x_vals), np.array(y_vals), np.array(z_vals))

cleaned_A = clean (A, t=2.5, dt=0.001)
x_f, y_f, z_f = get_surface (X, Y, Z, cleaned_A )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', aspect='equal')
ax.scatter(x_f, y_f, z_f, color='g', s=1)
```

I have also tried `ax.plot_trisurf(x_f,y_f,z_f)`, but this gives me an poorly connected plot. I'm guessing that the ordering of values in my arrays might be affecting this, in which case is there a package that can do some kind of 3D interpolated surface plot with random ordering of points (e.g. through minimizing the surface area or something like that?)

The object that I am interested in is roughly spherical (i.e. two z's per (x,y)). I can't seem to find any working examples of someone triangulating over a closed 3D surface, but maybe I'm not looking in the right places.

Comment: Do you know more or less the shape of the plot? For example, how many values of z would correspond to the same x,y pair?

Comment: I think `plot_trisurf` is the right approach. However, as you noted, it fails if your selected points do not form a nice, smooth surface. As a first pass, I would hence compute the hull surrounding your point cloud using `scipy.spatial.Delaunay`, and then plot the points of that triangulation.

Comment: @xg.plt.py The plot will be roughly a sphere with possible deformities but always two z values per (x,y) pair. Is there a way to apply this information in the plotting?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thanks for the tip. I'm a bit confused about how/why to implement Delaunay prior to `plot_trisurf` (isn't Delaunay  the default traingulation in `plot_trisurf` or am I missing something?)

Comment: Matplotlib's `plot_trisurf` does indeed use a Delaunay triangulation by default, and the Delaunay triangulation only takes into account the x and y values to triangulate. Thus, if the same x,y pair has more than one possible value, it ends up drawing vertical or nearly vertical triangles. Therefore, the result is not the surface of the figure but a mess of triangles crossing the figure.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging around, I think I've arrived at a solution that works (for a sphere at least--will update my answer when I try out deformations of a sphere). Many thanks to the comments which helped me think down the right path. I am basically using a `ConvexHull` for the triangulation from `scipy.spatial`:

```
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

def clean (A, t, dt):
    # function for making A binary for t+-dt
    # t is the target value I want in the matrix A with tolerance dt
    new_A = np.copy(A)
    new_A[np.logical_and(new_A > t-dt, new_A < t+dt)] = -1
    new_A[new_A != -1] = 0
    new_A[new_A == -1] = 1
    return (new_A)

def get_surface (X, Y, Z, new_A):
    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    z_vals = []

    # Retrieve (x,y,z) coordinates of surface
    for i in range(new_A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(new_A.shape[1]):
            for k in range(new_A.shape[2]):
                if new_A[i,j,k] == 1.0:
                    x_vals.append(X[i,j,k])
                    y_vals.append(Y[i,j,k])
                    z_vals.append(Z[i,j,k])

    return (np.array(x_vals), np.array(y_vals), np.array(z_vals))

cleaned_A = clean (A, t=2.5, dt=0.001)
x_f, y_f, z_f = get_surface (X, Y, Z, cleaned_A )

Xs = np.vstack((x_f, y_f, z_f)).T
hull = ConvexHull(Xs)
x, y, z = Xs.T

tri = Triangulation(x, y, triangles=hull.simplices)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', aspect='equal')
ax.plot_trisurf(tri, z, color='g', alpha=0.1)
```